# APCu and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, apc

Since PHP 5.5 broke APC in favor of their own cache, I'm trying to get my Symfony2 project running with APCu instead, and it doesn't like it:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in /home/maf/symfony/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php on line 40
```

The documentation of APCu is basically non-existent, and the Symfony2 docs are outdated, providing help only for APC.

I regret using PHP these days with all the compatibility-breaking upgrades, but I need to get my project running again. Where do I apply the gaffer tape?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony / PHP7 APC -> APCu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537523/symfony-php7-apc-apcu)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should make sure that you have APC support emulated, so make sure that you have `extension=apcu.so` (version >= 4.0) in your `php.ini`.

[image: APC support emulated on PHP 5.5]

Comment: I have that, and APCu seems to work (at least the web-frontend tells me so). I still get the above error.

Comment: Make sure that web and cli version of php.ini has it (`php -i | grep php.ini`, `php -m | grep apc`). I have no other advice at the moment.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Yes, I had it installed only for the web, not for the CLI, and Symfony2 calls it as CLI on cache clear. Thanks.