# Symfony / PHP7 APC -> APCu

Tags: php, symfony, apc

I have issue with PHP7 and APCu. After installation I got this error:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()`

APCu is 100% enabled, I see it in the `phpinfo();` And when I try `apcu_fetch()` it works.

How to use APCu in Symfony 2.8?

Comment: Opcache has been available, built into PHP since 5.5, might want to look into it.

Comment: Yes, but APCu is better for Symfony.

Comment: Do you get this error on command line or on the client which connects to fpm ? Anway just reminding, if you get this error on commandline, you may miss php.ini can be different by fpm and cli

Comment: APC is very buggy especially in newer PHP versions.

Comment: In php.ini I have this 
**extension=apcu.so**
**apc.enabled = 1**
And in phpinfo I see APCU like Enabled.. So it's OK. But in command line I have this error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()
If I try apc**u**_fetch() all works fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is obsolet. The correct answer is the one from François Breton.

In PHP 7 you have to add an additional module to your PHP setup: apc.so 
This is a module that enables backward compability to apc for apcu. 
This is kind of confusing...

See http://php.net/manual/de/apcu.installation.php for more info.

If you are using packages from https://deb.sury.org/ (ondrej ppa), you can install it via `apt-get install php-apcu-bc`.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer in how to add the module?

Answer (score 20):

You can update Doctrine, at least its doctrine/cache dependency (>= [1.6](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/releases/tag/v1.6.0))  **APCu** now supported :-)

Comment: Confirmed.  Just change all your configs where you have apc to apcu eg `metadata_cache_driver: apcu`

Answer (score 3):

If you use ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-apcu-bc
```

Comment: This answer contains the solution that worked for me. Be good if you fleshed it out a bit more. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, using pecl is a one-command solution (after a `brew install php@7.1`) :

`pecl install apcu`

downloading apcu-5.1.17.tgz ...
[...]
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.27/pecl/20160303/apcu.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/apcu-5.1.17
Extension apcu enabled in php.ini